# Writing a fixed length byte array to a binary file in Matlab

Tags: c++, c, matlab, binaryfiles

I need to write a binary file from Matlab which is going to read by a c program.

the .h files defines the string I'm trying to write as

```
char elem[16]
```

On the matlab side:

```
str = 'abc' % A variable length string <= 15 chars
fwrite(fp, str, 'char*1')
```

I'm not sure how to force matlab to add a null char to str and buffer it with "garbage" until the proper size so the c program can read it.

Note I can't modify the c code so I need to get Matlab to write out the file in the proper format.

Comment: The null character is essentially **zero**.  As such, simply write zero at the end of your string... not the **character** zero... the actual number zero.

Comment: @rayryeng as a person how doesn't know matlab well is there a preferred way to buffer a string with zeros to a desired length?

Comment: You need to use NaN, not 0.  A 0 will be output to a file as the character '0'.  '0' != '\0'.

Comment: Yes, simply figure out how many zeroes you need from the length of your string.  In this case, you have three characters stored in `abc`, so you need 16 - 3 = 13 zeroes.  As such, do something like this after your first `fwrite` call: `fwrite(fp, zeros(1,13), 'uint8');`.  Mind you I haven't tested this out yet, so try this out and let me know.

Comment: @ChrisCM - No.  If you write the number 48, then this will write the character `0` to the file as ASCII code 48, which translates to the character `0`.  Try it out yourself by doing: `fwrite(1, 0, 'char*1');` compared to `fwrite(1, 48, 'char*1');`.  The file ID `1` will write to your screen.  You'll see that the first statement displays nothing on your screen, while the second statement displays the number `0`.  Writing the actual number `0` to file should simulate the null character... mind you, this is all speculation.  I haven't actually tried it.. so I'm not sure if this will work!

Comment: You might be right, as long as you use the correct encoding.

Comment: @ChrisCM - I agree!  Let's see what the OP says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is what I ended up with.  Zeros ended up being the null character.  Not sure if there is a more elegant solution.

```
out_str = "abc";
out_len = 16; 
fwrite(fid_out, out_str, 'char*1'); 
fwrite(fid_out, zeros(1,out_len - length(out_str)),'char*1');
```